# Mobile broadband SIM not connecting via laptop

Tags: windows-7, networking, laptop, hp-elitebook, mobile-broadband

I have an HP EliteBook Folio 9480m Windows 7 and have inserted a SIM card for Telstra mobile broadband.

Usually when I use the same type of SIM on similar laptops then the connection to the internet works without a login screen.

However, on this laptop, there is a connection screen as follows:

```
Connect to a Network:
Type your Telstra subscription details

(three fields) Access point name, User name, Password.
```

I don't have any data to enter into these fields. I've called Telstra to confirm that the SIM is set up correctly.

I need to find a way to bypass this Connect to a Network windows/alert.

Comment: The same thing happens with a phone, when you insert a new SIM card. Usually the APN is `net` and the user/password fields are left empty. You should ask your provider for the internet settings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex.  I tried `net` which did not work.  I looked up the provider APN and entered those details as you suggested.  The laptop is now connected to the broadband connection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter the provider APN.
2. Leave the user/password fields blank.

> Solution provided by Alex in comments.